# How JInternalFrame is getting maximized when parent JFrame is maximized?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe, maximize-window

i am analyzing a issue raised by my client. we are having a JFrame and inside that we have 6 JInternalFrames. If any one of the JInternalFrame is maximized and if we open another JInternalFrame from this JInternalFrame then new JInternalFrame will also open in the maximized state. Similary if it is in restore mode then another JInternallFrame will open in the restore mode. I need to know how the new opening JInternalFrame is determining that the parent frame is in maximized or restore mode.

Thanks to all for your consideration.

```
public Object openEditor(String p_editorClassName) {

Object editorObject = null;

try {

// is this window already open

editorObject = m_editorList.get(p_editorClassName);

boolean isNewEditor = editorObject == null;

if (isNewEditor)

{

   ++m_openFrameCount;editorObject = createNewEditor(p_editorClassName);

m_editorList.put(p_editorClassName, editorObject);

}

int defaultWidth = editorObject instanceof IEditor ? ((IEditor)editorObject).getDefaultEditorWidth() : IDEConstants.DEFAULT_EDITOR_WIDTH;

int defaultHeight = editorObject instanceof IEditor ? ((IEditor)editorObject).getDefaultEditorHeight() : IDEConstants.DEFAULT_EDITOR_HEIGHT;

        if (editorObject instanceof JInternalFrame)
        {
            JInternalFrame editorFrame = (JInternalFrame) editorObject;
            if (isNewEditor)
            {
                ((GenericEditor)editorFrame).setQFTestName(((JInternalFrame)editorObject).getTitle());
                editorFrame.setSize(defaultWidth, defaultHeight);
                editorFrame.setVisible(true);
                addFrameToDesktop(editorFrame);
                editorFrame.setLocation(XOFFSET * m_openFrameCount, YOFFSET * m_openFrameCount);

                if (editorObject instanceof GenericEditor)
                { 
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
                    String strCount = df.format(m_editorList.size());
                    String editorKey = EditorsIDEState.PROP_EDITOR + strCount;
                    ((GenericEditor)editorObject).setState(getIDEState().getProps(), editorKey, p_editorClassName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Need to undo minimize here, otherwise it will return null for getParent() and will
                // then re-add back into desktop below
                //
                if (editorFrame.isIcon())
                {
                    editorFrame.setIcon(false);
                }

                // Check to see if we have ever been added to the desktop
                //
                if (editorFrame.getParent() == null)
                {
                    addFrameToDesktop(editorFrame);
                }

                if (editorFrame.getWidth() < 1 && editorFrame.getHeight() < 1)
                {
                    // width and height is not visible, so set the size back to the original
                    editorFrame.setSize(defaultWidth, defaultHeight);
                }
                else if (editorFrame.getWidth() < 1)
                {
                    // width is not visible, so set the width back to the original
                    editorFrame.setSize(defaultWidth, editorFrame.getHeight());
                }
                else if (editorFrame.getHeight() < 1)
                {
                    // height is not visible, so set the height back to the original
                    editorFrame.setSize(editorFrame.getWidth(), defaultHeight);
                }

                // is this window still visible
                if (editorFrame.isClosed())
                {
                    // to reopen an JInternalFrame, re-attach to container
                    editorFrame.setVisible(true);
                    editorFrame.setClosed(false);
                    addFrameToDesktop(editorFrame);
                }
                if (!editorFrame.isVisible())
                {
                    editorFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            editorFrame.setSelected(true);
            editorFrame.moveToFront();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return editorObject;
}
```

while debugging i have IsMaximum FALSE till second last line i.e. editorFrame.setSelected(true); after this i will get the IsMaximum as TRUE

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The issue is in code that you've not shown us.

Comment: *"I need to know how the new opening JInternalFrame is determining that the parent frame is in maximized or restore mode."*  Put aside the 'how?' for the moment & answer the 'what?'.  What feature would you wish to implement in the application, knowing that information?  BTW - are you aware of [`JInternalFrame.setMaximum(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setMaximum%28boolean%29)?  Though hard to query, it is easy to control.

Comment: i have pasted the code. thanks

Comment: don't post the exact same question several times - instead do your best to make it easy for others to reproduce your problem and possibly find a solution. Voted to close the others. Anyway, if you are so desparate/impatient for a solution that you feel like re-posting after only an hour, you might consider hiring a consultant - s/he'll guarantee her full attention :-)

Comment: btw, please fix that horrible code formatting - it's unreadable as-is